# Custom function for Google Spreadsheet - handling the array passed from the spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, custom-function

I am trying to build a simple script to work with a Google Spreadsheet. The spreadsheet takes input from a Google Form, so there is a series of values in the spreadsheet like this:

[image: http://i43.tinypic.com/2losg5.jpg]

My goal is to write a script that would strip the number from each form input in a user-specified range, then add all the numbers to provide a single score. So, for example, the user could type `=sumColumns(H2:K2)` in a cell, and it would return the sum of the scores (for the sample screenshot I posted, it would return the result of `3+3+0+3`, `9`).

Here is the code that I wrote to do this:

```
function sumColumns(values) {
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i <= values.length; i++){
    var input = values[0][i];
    var x = input.toString();
    var y = x.charAt(0);
    var num = parseInt(y);
    sum += num;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

The problem is that it only ever seems to add two values together. So, when I put `=sumColumns(H2:K2)` in a cell in the spreadsheet, it only returns `6`. Also, on line 3, if I change it from `i <= values.length` to `i < values.length` it only adds one number, so that I  get `3` as a result. My guess is that I am misunderstanding the way that the Google Spreadsheet values are passed to the function, but I have been completely unable to make it work. I'd really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3):

Oops - edited & saved the question, wrote an answer - and forgot to save it. I let Serge beat me to it! And, as usual, Serge's answer works well (with integer values). But you did ask about how things worked, so here you go.

When you give a Custom Function a range as a parameter, `H2:K2` in this case, the function receives a two-dimensional array, equivalent to the return value of `Range.getValues()`. You can test this easily, by (temporarily) changing your function to return a JSON representation of the parameter:

```
function sumColumns(values) {
  return JSON.stringify(values);   // For debugging, just return string showing values
  ...
```

Here's what you'll see in the cell that contains `=sumColumns(H2:K2)`:

```
[["3 (Rarely)","3 (Frequently)","0 (Never)","3 (Frequently)"]]
```

That's showing an Array enclosed by `[ .. ]`, with another Array inside, also enclosed by square brackets, and that array has four elements. If we change the range to be `H2:K3` instead, we get this (with whitespace added for clarity):

```
[
  ["3 (Rarely)","3 (Frequently)","0 (Never)","3 (Frequently)"],
  ["","","",""]
]
```

Now that you know that, it's easy to see why your function was giving the results it did.

First, `for(var i = 0; i <= values.length; i++)` is using the wrong array bounds to loop over, since `values.length` will tell us how many *rows* are in `values`. In `H2:K2`, that length is `1`. Instead, we need to be looping over the columns in the first row (`values[0]`), with its `4` cells.

You were wondering about `<` vs `<=` for this loop - we do need to use `<` since it's a 0-based index, and `.length` returns a count of elements. So we end up with:

```
for (var i=0; i < values[0].length; i++){ ... }
```

Using `parseInt()` is a good choice, and works well for the values in your spreadsheet. It can be improved, though, by ensuring that any String values have leading non-numeric values stripped first - `parseInt()` can then find an Integer inside a string.

```
function sumColumns(values) {
  return JSON.stringify(values);   // For debugging, just return string showing values
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < values[0].length; i++){
    var input = new String(values[0][i])
                 .replace( /^\D+/g, '');    // Strip any leading non-digits
    sum += parseInt(input);
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good with custom function because I never use them but it seems that `values` is not really an array...

---

Comments in italic :

*Hmmm embarrassing ... my first though was that it had to be a 2D array but I logged val[0] in my test and it returned an 'undefined' error... I must have mistyped something at that moment... Anyway, that's why I looked for a way around handling data as a string and using split and regex.
   As usual with Mogsdad's answers you have an answer and all the explanations that go with it ;-) and, as often with him too, you get a better answer than mine.
(one restriction though (@Mogsdad) your comment about non integer values could be applied to your code as well... you simply strip out any decimal value with parseInt()...:-) 
That said, your use case was well described and in the limits of this example both code should work as expected, Mogsdad's one being more 'academic' and programmatically correct.*

end of comment.

---

Using this trick below it works as expected for any input range (1 or more row and columns):

```
function sumCol(val) { // returns the sum of all numeric values in range
  var values = val.toString().split(',');
  var sum = 0;
  for(var n=0;n<values.length;++n){
    sum+=Number(values[n].replace(/[^0-9+.]/ig,''));
  }
  return sum;
}
```

I changed also the number extraction mode to make it more universal.